# Sum of array values

Tags: php, arrays

```
$weektotnos = array(); 
$sums = 0;
foreach($reportlists as $reportlist)
{       
    foreach($reportlist as $reps)
    {
        $sums+=$reps['total_working_days'];      
        $weektotnos[date('W',strtotime($reps['work_date']))] = $sums;
    }
}
```

Got this ,

```
Array ( [10] => 5 [11] => 13 )
```

But need this array of format,

```
Array ( [10] => 5 [11] => 8 )
```

Thanks to Advance!

Comment: What's the logic? and what did you try?

Comment: Explain algorithm, what you placed here is nonsense, you can't get array with the same keys, You can get something like `[10 => [2,1,2], 11 => [2,6]]` but still we don't understand logic.

Comment: @szapio : how to get [10] => [2,1,2], [11]=>[2,6]

Comment: @Kumar Ramalingam, im asking you. I just wrote that you can't have array with two or more same keys, key is unique so i place array in array example. I don't know what you want to achieve and logic that you want to use so i can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $sumArray = array();
    $sumval = 0;
    foreach ($reportlists as $k=>$subArray) {        
      foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {

        if (isset($sumArray[date('W',strtotime($value['work_date']))]))
        {
        $sumArray[date('W',strtotime($value['work_date']))] += $value['total_working_days'];
        }
        else
        {
        $sumArray[date('W',strtotime($value['work_date']))] = $value['total_working_days'];
        }   
      }
    }
```

Result :

Array ( [10] => 5 [11] => 43 )

Refer :

http://laravel.io/bin/JxoRa

Answer (score 0):

Requires PHP >= 5.5

```
$array1 = [10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11];
$array2 = [2,  1,  2,  0,  2,  6];

$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array1));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array2));
$newArray = [];
foreach($mi as list($key, $value)) {
    $newArray[$key] = isset($newArray[$key]) ?  $newArray[$key] + $value : $value;
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

for earlier versions of PHP, you can use

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL | MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array1), 'key');
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array2), 'value');
$newArray = [];
foreach($mi as $details) {
    extract($details);
    $newArray[$key] = isset($newArray[$key]) ?  $newArray[$key] + $value : $value;
}
```